# How to delete a row that contains a specific string in Python using numpy？

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Now I have a huge data ndarray as below, which contains 200 million rows.

```
[['5040' '5' 'load_video' '2015-03-30 12:31:27.727452'
['5040' '44' 'load_video' '2015-03-30 12:33:26.764407']
['5040' '34' 'load_video' '2015-03-30 12:31:26.102226']
 ..., 
['3076' '1' 'play_video' '2015-05-31 05:52:33.395859']
['3076' '1' 'seek_video' '2015-05-31 05:52:36.941808']
['1512' '8' 'load_video' '2015-05-31 07:19:56.715000']]]
```

What I want to do is to delete all rows that contain 'load_video" string. Is there any solution to do this?

PS: What I want to do next is to sort the rows according to the first column, but since it's string type and I found it impossible to use `astype` to only change the first row into int, what can I do?

These might be some very simple questions, but since I am new to python, your answers would help me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Since the data set is quite huge, I think solution with np.apply_along_axis() would be better.

Comment: Aside: if you're working with non-numerical data you're probably going to have a much better time using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) than pure numpy.

Comment: @DSM You mean using a dataframe from pandas?

Comment: ndarray seems to be an odd choice for this data structure. pandas dataframe is more suitable.

Comment: @Vinnton: yep. For tabular data with different column types, using a frame will make life much easier.

Comment: @sharatpc Yeah now I am trying on it! It's a lot more convenient to use pd.DataFrame.

Comment: @DSM Yes I found it too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the python to remove any entry with 'load_video'.

```
new_list = [x for x in old_list if 'load_video' not in x]
```

Comment: But unfortunately I got an error `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split'` ?

Comment: I modify your solution to `TrainData = [x for x in TrainData if x[2] != 'load_video']` and it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, you'd need to use your own list name instead of old_list, glad it works!!